# Enqueue Wordpress plugin scripts below all other JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a simple Wordpress app but I am having an issue as all of the plugin scripts are rendered before those which are enqueued in my `functions.php`.

Here is a sample section of the `functions.php`:

```php
function my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('app-js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

The important this to note is that (following best practice my JS is set to render at the bottom of the page.

I also have couple of plugins running on the theme. The problem is that the output looks like this:

```html
<!-- Note the plugin appears first -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/acl-plugin.js'></script>
<!-- And the main JS appears second -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/javascripts/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I force Wordpress to display the main JS (which i believe is rendered by `wp_head()` to appear at the very bottom of the page?

Comment: Where did you read about this "best practice"? I'm curious because I'm currently working on changing it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The WordPress **wp_head()** method will only output scripts or styles that have that last parameter in the WordPress **wp_enqueue_script()** set to **false**.. when it is set to **true** it will render in the footer via the **wp_footer()**

you can change the priority of when its called and inserted by adjusting the **$priority** parameter in the **add_action()**

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action**

> $priority
>       (int) (optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action. Default: 10

```
add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

And also look at the following two WordPress methods:

**wp_enqueue_script()** :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

**wp_register_script()** :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

```
wp_register_script( string $handle, string $src, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Try this..

You might have to play with that **$priority** parameter

```
function my_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script('app-js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts', 20, 1);
```

Comment: That's the chicken! Thanks buddy!

Comment: Edit button disabled. For completeness it would be nice to indicate the `wp_enqueue_script()` default in your answer.

Comment: If you look at the first sentence in my answer and my code snippet. You will see that I set the last parameter to `true`, so that means the default is `false`. But as you wish, i added the WP methods above next to the links to the Wordpress Codex API for `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_register_script()` :)